# angularjs - how to convert a input element because a list element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to make a dropdown in the text element. I have these goals too:

1. on typing of a user, the month as well need to reset (filter) in the list. ( ex: user types jan, the all the month has the same letters need to filtered in the list).
2. when user nothing selected from the list, i need to show the error.
3. user should not remove month  manually in the text field and not fill by himself in the text field.
4. there is no list value in the text field, then the form need to disabled.

How to get this all?

my code :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.months = [
                "January", "February", "March", 
                "April", "May", "June", "July",  
                "August", "September", "October",
                "November", "December"
            ];

  $scope.defaultMonth = 'Select a Month';

  $scope.showList = false;

  $scope.setMonth = function ( month ) {
    console.log( month );
    $scope.defaultMonth = month;
    $scope.showList=false;
  }

});
```

[Here is my try](http://plnkr.co/edit/V77haIuQ6hxRPSmxYA3F?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue, you may use a filter on your input:

```
ng-repeat="month in months | filter:defaultMonth"
```

Your second issue can be solved by adding a `required` into your input and adding this into your html:

```
<span ng-show="monthForm.selectMonth.$error.required">Please enter something!</span>
```

But your are contradicting yourself with issue number 3. The text input shall filter user input, but the user should not be able to fill the input by himself? Issue number 4 I do not understand either. Please clarify that...

([my edited plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bqqpj5Qc6sjzZnakYaNa?p=preview))

Comment: the 4th point is, you can just type a string other then selecting a month from the drop down, still it became valid. but i want to restrict to select from the list, else user can type from the list, not themselves typing ( say:'foo')  something other than the list item. - needs further clarification let me know

Comment: Then you can use a [ng-pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input) directive in your input

Comment: I am happy to learn the ng-patten wok progress. as a help can you teach me updating the plunker?